# R - Extracting numeric data from character vector based on recurring string that follows number

Tags: regex, r, twitter, vector

I'd like to extract numeric information from  a character vector in R. Every line in the vector has the same structure, and it as follows:

```
  [1] "Capturing tweets..."                                                                    
  [2] "Connection to Twitter stream was closed after 1 seconds with up to 1 tweets downloaded."
  [3] "Capturing tweets..."                                                                    
  [4] "Connection to Twitter stream was closed after 1 seconds with up to 1 tweets downloaded."
  [5] "Capturing tweets..."                                                                    
  [6] "Connection to Twitter stream was closed after 1 seconds with up to 1 tweets downloaded."
  [7] "Capturing tweets..."                                                                    
  [8] "Connection to Twitter stream was closed after 1 seconds with up to 1 tweets downloaded."
  [9] "Capturing tweets..."
```

As you can see, there are two kinds of recurring numeric information in this vector. One that outlines the duration of the open connection, i.e. number followed by "seconds", and another indicating the number of tweets downloaded. I require only the number of tweets, so I'd like to generate a new, numeric vector that contains only the number which is followed by "tweets" for every line.

Comment: Anything you've already tried yourself?

Comment: Hi @Heroka, I've tried several variations of 'gsub', e.g. this: 

    `tweetnumbers <- as.numeric(gsub("[^\\d]+", "", output, perl=TRUE))`

However, this simply left an '11' for each line.

Comment: @nikUoM, I suggest editing your question to include the most promising attempts you've had so far (the above comment is fine but would work best when added to the question) so that people have something more concrete to help you with.

Answer (score 4):

Your regex must be,

```
as.numeric(sub(".*?(\\d+) tweets.*","\\1",x))
```

`.*` after the `tweets` is a much needed one so that it would remove all the chars which exists next to tweets.

```
x <- c("Capturing tweets...", "Connection to Twitter stream was closed after 1 seconds with up to 1 tweets downloaded.")
as.numeric(sub(".*?(\\d+) tweets.*","\\1",grep("\\d+ tweets", x, value=TRUE)))
# [1] 1
```

Why I used `.*?` instead of `.*` ?

Because `.*` is greedy which matches all the characters upto the last. Then it backtracks in-order to find a match. So it backtracks (reverse traversing) upto the digit which exists before `tweets` and it stops capturing all the digits exists next to the first digit because of `\\d+` (atleast one digit. So it finds a match) . Now it won't go back to the second character since the condition is satisfied `\\d+`, match one or more digit chars.

Comment: weird, I just realised this was the same code as the one in your comment - all i did was use a new vector name to assign this to.

Comment: @nikUoM it's because it tries to convert the string which won't contain num tweets as numeric. So first grep the strings which contain numtweets and then apply sub.